# after truncated log file in linux,the new created file was filled with many \0

Tags: linux, shell

Firstly,i will give the shell code:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$1
if [ -e $filename ] ; then
    yesterday=`date -d yesterday +%Y%m%d`

    cp $filename $filename.$yesterday
    now=`date '+%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S'`
    echo "========split log at $now========" > $filename
    echo "========split log $filename to $filename.$yesterday  at $now========"
else
    echo "$filename not exist."
fi
```

The shell run successfully,and print the string `========split log at $now========` to the new created `$filename`.But below this string,many bytes of `\0`  are also written to the`$filename`,which is showed as follows:

**My reputation score is less than 10,i can not post image,so i give the link of the picture:https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF0F2.jpg**

Comment: Two pairs of 0x0D 0x0A look very strange.

Comment: There was a command of `echo "" >> $filename` after `echo "========split log at $now========" > $filename` in my original code,so you can see `0x0d` and `0x0a`.

Comment: In Linux, I would expect to see only 0x0A (no 0x0D). Which Linux do you use? Also, is the file local?

Comment: 0x0d is not the key point,i have changed the picturue,which has none 0x0d

Answer (score 1):

i wrote the shell code aimed to truncate the log file created by nohup.
The original of my start command like this : `nohup $cmd  > $logPath 2>&1  &`,
now i change it to `nohup $cmd  >> $logPath 2>&1  &`.Someone told me that when use the mode of `>` the log writer program would remember the location of current log, and after truncating the log,the program will continue the location.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the OP's issue. The OP is not using `>` *after* truncating the file, (s)he is using `>` *to* truncate the file (and write to it).

Comment: Wait, never mind, I see what you're saying. The problem is not in the script the OP posted, but in the process that's actually writing to these files. (Of course, we don't know for sure that that process is just using a Bash redirect, but it's quite possible.) +1